# Azure Virtual Machine Images Tomcat SSL

Tags: ssl, tomcat, azure, image

Here's the run by, yes I have done research on all of what I am about to say. I simply wish to summarize it and hope someone with knowledge on this can let me know if something is wrong with my plan of action.

1. I am going to purchase a wildcard ssl certificate from either Comodo or RapidSSL.
2. I am going to generate the csr, upload it to them, get my certificate and install it to tomcat.
3. Here's where I am worried, I am going to create an Azure Virtual Machine Image to duplicate the VM with my tomcat web app and the installed ssl. I will end up soon having up to 20 Virtual Machines based on that same image with the same tomcat application, same keystore, same certificate, but simply a different url pointing to the Azure CNAME server.
   Do you all see any problem with #3?

Can the same keystore and certificate be on multiple servers with an image, or will I have a problem with this process?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they can. In fact, even if you had to setup one by one instead of cloning, you'd have to configure SSL exactly the same way using the same certificate files.

A wildcard certificate allows you to have multiples hosts. Something like www1.example.com, www2.example.com, etc. but even for different hosts (of the same domain), the certificate files would still be the same on this case.

Comment: Last quick question, when making my csr I need to put my domain name, not the Azure cloudapp.net domain name? I have a cname that forwards my domain to a random cloudapp.net subdomain for Azure.

Comment: You use your own domain name.